# Getting "Service unavailable since initialization is not yet complete." message after deploying worklight war file in server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I have deployed my worklight project war file and I'm getting

> "Service unavailable since initialization is not yet complete."

message when I tried to access my app in browser as `http://hostname:Port/App_name/console/#catalog`.'App_name' is the context path that given while deploying. Worklight console is installed in the server and it is working fine.worklight version is 6.2.

Comment: You're missing out a lot of information: server logs, how you've deployed it, the full qualified URL (for example - that URL you mention, looks actually *wrong*, so show us what you're actually using (mask any private names you cannot disclose)).

Comment: URL is http://hostname:Port_number/App_name/console/#catalog.'App_name' is the context path that given while deploying. For deploying I followed steps from http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/06/18/deploy-worklight-war-file-into-websphere/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worklight 6.2 is very much different from Worklight 6.1; don't follow outdatd online material.

You can find up-to-date materials for deploying artifacts (.war, .wlapp, .adapter, ...) in the IBM Worklight Foundation Knowledge Center: [Deploying IBM Worklight applications to test and production environments](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/t_transporting_apps_and_adapters.html)

Also, that is the wrong URL structure to access the Worklight Console.
This is the correct one: `http://my-ip-address:my-port/worklightconsole/`.